# complex zeros of difference of $n$th powers of affine polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I am trying to find the general complex solutions to the equation
$$(az-b)^n=(cz-d)^n,$$

assuming $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace$ and all are distinct, which is naturally satisfied by
$$z_0=\dfrac{b-d}{a-c}$$
with (I think) multiplicity $1$ but as this is equivalent to the zeros of a complex polynomial of degree $n$, there are $n-1$ solutions missing, by the fundamental theorem of algebra. I tried to adjoin a root of unity $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi i n^{-1}}$ to $z_0$ to obtain further solutions, but that failed. How do I find the remaining solutions as a function of $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: $(az-b)=(cz-d)w$ where $w$ is an $n-$th root of unity. Solving this for $z$ is a piece of cake.

Comment: Wow, thank you, I take a piece of blackwood forest cake since I already did not see the mathematical forest for all its trees...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment, I can give the solution here. Any $z_j$ is given by

$$z_j=\frac{d-b e^{\frac{2\pi i j}{n}}}{c-a e^{\frac{2\pi i j}{n}}}$$

for $j\in\lbrace 0,...,n-1\rbrace$ and I thank you for the cake.